Fridge has error code and the freezer fan is not running correctly - how to fix?
Have an LG fridge . Not build up on fans but have a code on the fridge that says "Er IF". Google it and it states that my freezer fan motor does not operate normally. Before getting this code I noticed a sorta crackling noise then next day woke up with that code. What are the next steps?

Likely, "LF" is "LG". Please edit into your question the model number on the label inside the refrigerator. This way we can get better starting information to help you. FWIW if you can get the perishable food out of the whole fridge then turn it off for a day with the doors open, does the code come back? (Might be ice buildup on the freezer coils, meaning a bad defroster.)

Got model number?

Start by checking if the owner's manual has suggested diagnostic steps for this error code. There may be some which you can do yourself. Next step is usually to call a repair technician, tell them what model you have and what error code you are getting, and ask them to come out and fix it. Knowing the error code will enable them to make sure the parts that might be necessary are in the vehicle.
(I have a technician showing up in 40 minutes to work on my heating system's F11 error code, "false flame indication", which probably means the igniter needs to be adjusted.)
If you really wanted to go after this yourself, you would be looking at disassembling the refrigerator to get to the fan, making sure the fan is not impeded by anything, seeing if the fan runs, and if not replacing it with the equivalent part. And if that doesn't solve it, you would be looking into why the fridge is reporting a problem with the fan when the fan appears to be okay. One step at a time.
Either way, of course, your food is currently not being refrigerated; you might want to consider moving food into a cooler or two with purchased ice until this is resolved.

I do not know what is LF, but if you want the fridge fixed and you cannot do it, then your best bet is to contact a service specialized in repairing fridges.
If the fridge is still under guarantee, then locate the closest authorized service that can fix it for free under guarantee.
